# How to display output in the same culture that was entered using "double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm pretty new to `C#`, `.NET` and programming on Windows in a general.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lineBreak = "\r\n";
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            double number = double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine("You've entered: " + number + lineBreak + "Variable type:" +number.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit . . .");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter `double` like this `"32,45"` (notice there is a comma as a separator), then I get output like this:

```
You've entered: 32,45
Variable type: System.Double
```

But when I enter `double` variable like this `"32.45"` (notice, there is dot instead of a comma), then I get output like this:

```
You've entered: 32,45
Variable type: System.Double
```

It's the same. I know that this is because of CultureInfo set on my local machine.

How can I make it kind of independent(not changing my settings or stuff, but exactly in my code? So when user opens my program, he shouldn't change anything in his settings)?

Like when I type dot it outputs double with dots and when I type comma it displays comma?

Best regards, Pāvels.

Comment: The way your code is written right now it will not be able to parse a number with a comma as the decimal separator. The .NET Framework does not directly support parsing both styles because that's ambiguous.

Comment: `double.Parse("32,45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` outputs `You've entered: 3245`

Comment: When dealing user input or output always use the default local culture.  When dealing with other processes/servers always use the Invariant culture.

Comment: I'm still learning, thanks for the advice, guys!
@TimSchmelter don't know why, but I see output the same as I have written in this question. I'm following tutorial and in the tutorial there was kinda different output (there was that kind of output I want to achieve).

Comment: @RichardSchneider: that's too general. If your users have been instructed to use a specific  format then this is what you should use and if you know the format of the server/process then use that, not `InvariantCulture`.